# GridView CommandField remove None-breaking space

Tags: .net, gridview

I have a command field in a GridView that is of ButtonType link. The markup that is produced is similar to;

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$GridView','Edit$0')">Edit</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$GridView','Delete$0')">Delete</a>
```

How do I get rid of the `&nbsp;` it is causing problems with my styles.

Comment: Similar issue on the question [gridview CommandField Update & cancel image coming Up down on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6094978/2012945).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use template field instead of command field;

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
      </ItemTemplate>
 
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Didn't really want to write the command logic but I suppose a TemplateField is the only thing that gives you enough control of the markup.

Comment: you don't have to. it's built in. Edit, Delete and Update. when you declare them as commandname, you will get the built-in function. try it.

Comment: Tried this under asp.net 4.5.1, and the default behavior (showing only the Edit link to start and then switching to the others) did *not* happen just because the CommandName matched.  Don't know if this is something that changed recently.

Answer (score 0):

Not the precise solution but a Workaround...

I had the same issue, and since I needed to use a *CommandField* (and not a *TemplateField*), I managed to solve the line break using the **ItemStyle Wrap**.

For example:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="True" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" CancelImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" Width="48px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:CommandField>
```

It can be either on the *CommandField* the attribute `ItemStyle-Wrap="false"`, or as its *ItemStyle* element with `Wrap="False"` attribute.

---

Although, it **does not remove** the `&nbsp;`, but applies the `white-space:nowrap;` CSS style, having the following when Edit mode:

```
<td style="width:48px;white-space:nowrap;">
    <input type="image" name="GridView1$ctl02$ctl00" src="images/update.png" alt="Update">
    &nbsp;
    <input type="image" src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Cancel$0');return false;">
</td>
```

Hope it helps.